# View controller crashes - newbie

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

my iOS view controller is crashing on this method below (`skipRegistration`).  It used to work, but now it is failing whenever Apple tries to approve the app.  Is there a way I can see what is wrong, or debug the exact cause of the crash?

Code:

```
@interface MPRegisterViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end

@implementation MPRegisterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle   *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {
      // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

   // for CoreData
   MPAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

   self.firstName.delegate = self;
   self.lastName.delegate = self;
   self.email.delegate = self;
   self.telephone.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[self.firstName resignFirstResponder];
[self.lastName resignFirstResponder];
[self.email resignFirstResponder];
[self.telephone resignFirstResponder];

return NO;
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

// Close the Mail Interface
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}


- (IBAction)skipRegistration:(id)sender {

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"skippedit" forKey: @"SkippedIt"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
}
@end
```

My stack trace is here;

Full Stack Trace:

> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x181d79e48  + 132 1
>   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x1929c80e4 _objc_exception_throw
>   + 60 2   UIKit                               0x18683ea40 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3376 3   UIKit                               0x1868408dc  + 120 4
>   UIKit                               0x1866160b4 -[UIViewController
>   presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 216

Comment: Have you tested a release build of the app?

Comment: Well, first you should get the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your `skipRegistration` seems to be the culprit, how is the view being presented? I would focus your attention here.